# How can I change the resolution of a raster using GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal

I am looking for the best way to change the resolution of a GDAL raster dataset.

For example, I have a raster that has a pixel size of (30, -30), and I would like to change the pixel size to (5, -5), interpolating all values for a given pixel into the output raster.

So for each pixel of the input raster, I would like to have 36 pixels in the output raster that all share the same value.

If I run `gdalwarp -tr 5 -5 inputRaster.tif outputRaster.tif`, I get exactly the result that I'm looking for, and so I would assume that I should be able to replicate this functionality with some GDAL function.

I would prefer to avoid using a call to python's Subprocess class, if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reproject the raster. For example, from an interactive Python shell:

```
from osgeo import gdal
help(gdal.ReprojectImage)
```

A Python example is provided in the [test suite](https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/autotest/alg/reproject.py).

More complete documentation is provided for the C++ function [GDALReprojectImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20180418112306/http://www.gdal.org:80/gdalwarper_8h.html#ad36462e8d5d34642df7f9ea1cfc2fec4).

Answer (score 6):

Use gdal.Warp function:

```
gdal.Warp('outputRaster.tif', 'inputRaster.tif', xRes=5, yRes=5)
```